# actionscript does not see changes to the textbox

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, database-connection

Here is the relevant AS3 code:

```
public function processLogin ():void {


        var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

        var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("php/controlpanel.php");


        phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

        var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;           
        phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);

        phpVars.systemCall = "checkLogin";
        phpVars.username = username.text;
        phpVars.password = password.text;

        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);


        if(result_text.text == "Welcome")
        {

        gotoscenetwo();
        }
        else{
        stop();
        }

        }
    public function showResult (event:Event):void {

        result_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.RIGHT;
        result_text.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;

        }
```

and my php code:

> include_once "connect.php";
>
> $username = $_POST['username'];
>   $password = $_POST['password'];
>
> if ($_POST['systemCall'] == "checkLogin") {
>
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
>
> $query = mysql_query($sql);
>
> $login_counter = mysql_num_rows($query);
>
> if ($login_counter > 0) {
>
> while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
>
> $username = $data["username"];
>
> print "systemResult=Welcome";
>
> }
>
> } else {
>
> print "systemResult=The login details dont match our records.";
>
> }
>
> }

This is my mini project. My problem is if as3 finds a matching record in the MySQL database, my `gotoscenetwo()` function starts to work. Thank you for help.

Comment: "My problem is if as3 finds a matching record in the MySQL database, my gotoscenetwo() function starts to work."  - I don't understand what you're asking.... you need to be more specific.

Comment: i have login screen in flash,
if username and password true,i want flash open the new page, "Harrison" solution way is correct but that not work in localhost i dont understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *if* need to be inside the function *showResult*

Comment: thats work in flash thank you. but again not work in local server.

Comment: problem is fixed now thank you so much. that was security problem. :)